# "fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories" after adding a Git remote

Tags: git, github

I've added a remote repository to the folder where I am working with:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
```

If I type:

```
git pull origin master
```

I get:

```
From https://github.com/<username>/<repo>
    * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

---

I have also tried:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

But I get:

```
From https://github.com/...
    * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    <files>
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

Comment: Are you starting the new repository?

Comment: About the second error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450049/what-does-would-be-overwritten-by-merge-mean

Comment: technically yes because it didn't find the repository that I was working .  SO i typed this :
```
git remote add origin https://github.co/username/xxxxx.git
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "would be overwritten by merge" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450049/what-does-would-be-overwritten-by-merge-mean)

Comment: `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories` .See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937984/git-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-on-rebase

Answer (score 54):

You need to either `reset` or `commit` your changes first:

```
git reset --hard
```

or:

```
git commit -m "saving changes..."
```

Then you can do:

```
git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Comment: I had the same problem and the command below solved it.  
`git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`  

I created a github repo (with one default file commited) and after that I created a local repository. So, the repos (remote and local) started independently and with different contents. That´s why --allow-unrelated-histories is necessary.

IMHO, this issues must be closed.

Comment: I have an annoying `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`