# how will I do PULL with keeping local changes in GIT

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-pull

As a team **we are working on same branch** in GIT. Now I want to check in my changes. But before that I need to do a pull. Its giving me a warning to clear my local changes before doing pull. How can I do a pull while making sure to keep local changes.

Comment: What local changes? Are they in index? If so, they can't be gone easily, you will see conflicts, but that's it. And better practice to run `git pull --rebase origin master` (remote and repository can be adjusted to your actual layout)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "would be overwritten by merge" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450049/what-does-would-be-overwritten-by-merge-mean)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-pull%5D+keep+local+changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's `pull` operation is a high level operation that does two things:

1. Downloads or `fetch`es the commit history from the server
2. Merges or rebases the current branch on to its upstream.

These operations can also be done stand alone.
This is the workflow I'd recommend:

1. Commit any uncommitted changes (you may also use `git stash` but I find it is easy to forget about the contents of your stash during the conflict resolution step)
2. Use `git fetch` to check for any upstream changes
3. Inspect the upstream changes using `git log`
4. `git rebase`
5. Resolve conflicts