# Unable to checkout when changes are present on your branch. The following files would be overwritten

Tags: git, github-for-windows

[image]

I can't change branch and merge code to current branch

Comment: You're seeing this through a different interface (github-for-windows, apparently) so I'm not sure if this counts as a true duplicate, but [What does "would be overwritten by merge" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35450049/1256452) has the reason here. There are numerous very-similar questions: just search stackoverflow for "would be overwritten".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "would be overwritten by merge" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450049/what-does-would-be-overwritten-by-merge-mean)

Comment: I think it's a duplicate. The message here shows the same advice as other interfaces would show, and the solution is the same.

Comment: I tried all answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450049/what-does-would-be-overwritten-by-merge-mean but still not working

Answer (score 1):

You have changes in your file `ios\AppCenter-Config.plist`. Do as the message tells you and `git stash` your changes or even `git revert` them, if you don't need them any more.

Checking out will change this file and git can't do that, if the file is already changed in your working copy.

Note that this can also happen when you created that file locally and now want to check out to a revision, where this file is part of the repository. In this case you should move the file out of the way, do the checkout and move it back in place.